# Clone HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a form with a main category drop-down and several sub-category drop-downs which will be displayed based on the chosen main category. Each main category has only one subcategory drop-down. So, it is a direct match between the category and subcategory. I am trying to use javascript to identify which category is selected and then hide the subcategories irrelevant to that.

I get all the sub-category elements using the class name. Then, I copy the elements to a new variable before trying to remove the specific element. However, the assignment to a new variable (subCategoryList_h) is not happening and it ends up undefined. I found that the variable type is HTMLCollection but I cannot figure out how to clone it or assign it to a new variable.

```js
const categoryValue = document.getElementById("category-list");
const subCategoryList = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-category");

function categoryChange() {
  console.log(categoryValue.value);
  switch (categoryValue.value) {
    case "Category_1":
      let subCategoryList_h = subCategoryList;
      subCategoryList_h.item(0).parentNode.removeChild(subCategoryList_h.item(0));
      //console.log(subCategoryList_h);
      subCategoryList_h.style.display = "none";
      break;
    case "Category_2":
      let subCategoryList_h = subCategoryList;
      subCategoryList_h.item(1).parentNode.removeChild(subCategoryList_h.item(1));
      //console.log(subCategoryList_h);
      subCategoryList_h.style.display = "none";
      break;
    case "Category_3":
      let subCategoryList_h = subCategoryList;
      subCategoryList_h.item(2).parentNode.removeChild(subCategoryList_h.item(2));
      //console.log(subCategoryList_h);
      subCategoryList_h.style.display = "none";
      break;
    case "Category_4":
      let subCategoryList_h = subCategoryList;
      subCategoryList_h.item(3).parentNode.removeChild(subCategoryList_h.item(3));
      //console.log(subCategoryList_h);
      subCategoryList_h.style.display = "none";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html lang="en">
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!--Required meta tags-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!--Reset Browser StyleSheet-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
  <!--Custom CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header_footer.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

  <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Form</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div>
      <h1>Survey</h1>
      <form name="survey">
        <div class="category" id="category">
          <label for="category">Category:</label>
          <select name="category" id="category-list" onchange="categoryChange()" required>
            <option value="Category_1">Category 1</option>
            <option value="Category_2">Category 2</option>
            <option value="Category_3">Category 3</option>
            <option value="Category_4">Category 4</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div id="sub-category">
          <!-- Sub-category drop down lists -->
          <div class="sub-category" id="sub-category-1">
            <label for="sub-category">Sub Category:</label>
            <select name="sub-category">
              <option value="Sub_Category_1">Sub_Category_1</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_2">Sub_Category_2</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_3">Sub_Category_3</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_4">Sub_Category_4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="sub-category" id="sub-category-2">
            <label for="sub-category">Sub Category:</label>
            <select name="sub-category">
              <option value="Sub_Category_1">Sub_Category_1</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_2">Sub_Category_2</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_3">Sub_Category_3</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_4">Sub_Category_4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="sub-category" id="sub-category-3">
            <label for="sub-category">Sub Category:</label>
            <select name="sub-category">
              <option value="Sub_Category_1">Sub_Category_1</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_2">Sub_Category_2</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_3">Sub_Category_3</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_4">Sub_Category_4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="sub-category" id="sub-category-4">
            <label for="sub-category">Sub Category:</label>
            <select name="sub-category">
              <option value="Sub_Category_1">Sub_Category_1</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_2">Sub_Category_2</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_3">Sub_Category_3</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_4">Sub_Category_4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>

  <!-- JavaScript references. Do not touch -->
  <script src="scripts/survey.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, if there are other efficient ways of doing it, please let me know.

Comment: `HTMLCollection` doesn't have a `style` property. Elements do. Aside from that, I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues which already appear in the console as errors:

- You cannot declare the same variable with `let` multiple times in the same block (even if in separate `case` sections)
- `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, which does not have a `style` property.

Also, removing elements that you never insert back, seems like a bad idea. You should only hide, not remove. Aim to avoid code repetition, so avoid the `switch`.

Below is how you could do it. I didn't change the HTML, but as you can see you don't need many of those `id` HTML attributes:

```js
const categoryValue = document.getElementById("category-list");
const subCategoryList = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-category");

function categoryChange() {
    subCategoryList.forEach((subCategory, i) => {
        subCategory.style.display = categoryValue.selectedIndex == i ? "" : "none";
    });
}

categoryChange(); // on page load
```

```html
  <main>
    <div>
      <h1>Survey</h1>
      <form name="survey">
        <div class="category" id="category">
          <label for="category">Category:</label>
          <select name="category" id="category-list" onchange="categoryChange()" required>
            <option value="Category_1">Category 1</option>
            <option value="Category_2">Category 2</option>
            <option value="Category_3">Category 3</option>
            <option value="Category_4">Category 4</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div id="sub-category">
          <!-- Sub-category drop down lists -->
          <div class="sub-category" id="sub-category-1">
            <label for="sub-category">Sub Category for 1:</label>
            <select name="sub-category">
              <option value="Sub_Category_1">Sub_Category_1</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_2">Sub_Category_2</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_3">Sub_Category_3</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_4">Sub_Category_4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="sub-category" id="sub-category-2">
            <label for="sub-category">Sub Category for 2:</label>
            <select name="sub-category">
              <option value="Sub_Category_1">Sub_Category_1</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_2">Sub_Category_2</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_3">Sub_Category_3</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_4">Sub_Category_4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="sub-category" id="sub-category-3">
            <label for="sub-category">Sub Category for 3:</label>
            <select name="sub-category">
              <option value="Sub_Category_1">Sub_Category_1</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_2">Sub_Category_2</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_3">Sub_Category_3</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_4">Sub_Category_4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="sub-category" id="sub-category-4">
            <label for="sub-category">Sub Category for 4:</label>
            <select name="sub-category">
              <option value="Sub_Category_1">Sub_Category_1</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_2">Sub_Category_2</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_3">Sub_Category_3</option>
              <option value="Sub_Category_4">Sub_Category_4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to web design. I didn't fully understand subCategoryList.forEach((subCategory, i) part. Do I have to replace subCategory and i with my element ids and index?

Comment: Note that I defined `subCategoryList` differently: not with `getElementsByClassName`, but with `querySelectorAll`. That is the modern way to do it. To iterate such node list, you can use `.forEach`. It is in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). The `subCategory` and `i` are parameters of a callback function that I defined using arrow syntax. You can also use a normal `function (subCategory, i) {` if you prefer. So nothing to change. You can see it runs here.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for sharing the documentation file.